# .CMD execution in C# inexplicably failing

Tags: c#, command-line, process

I'm attempting to execute a .cmd process from a C# program. When I run the process in command line, i.e.

```
C:\Directory\Process.cmd  -x 1000 -y 1000 C:\Input\input.txt
```

I get an appropriate result (in this case, that means that the process writes a file to:

```
C:\Output\output.txt
```

However, When I try to run this process from a simple C# program, the output file is not created. Here are a couple of my attempts:

Attempt 1)

```
try
{
    string processName = @"C:\Directory\Process.cmd";
    string argString = @" -x 1000 -y 1000 C:\Input\input.txt"; //The extra space in front of the '-x' is here on purpose
    Process prs = new Process();
    prs.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    prs.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
    prs.StartInfo.FileName = processName;
    prs.StartInfo.Arguments = argString;
    prs.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;

    prs.Start()
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.Writeline(e.Message);
}
```

Attempt 2)

```
try
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\\Directory\\Process.cmd", " -x 1000 -y 1000 C:\\Input\\input.txt";
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.Writeline(e.message);
}
```

Now, in both cases, no exceptions are thrown, and Process.cmd is accessed (it prints status updates in a shell), but the process does not create any output files. Is there something wrong with the way I am attempting to call Process.cmd, that it works properly when run directly form the command line but does not work properly when I attempt to call it from my C# program?

Comment: Can you post the process.cmd content?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot (I dont have access to it). I know that process.cmd calls a Java application that processes data and produces output, though.

Comment: Does the process need administrator privileges to execute and write the output? Have you checked that the C# program is run with the correct privileges?

Comment: Should UseShellExecute not be true if you are running a batch file?

Comment: Can you post the code that generates `Output.txt`?

Comment: If you don't have access to it, how can you launch the command?

Comment: I only have the .cmd, and that just calls the java executable. I don't have access to the java source code.

Comment: Try the suggestion of set the WorkingDirectory even if you pass the full path in the arguments of the Process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was finally able to get my hands on the source code, and realized that the problem was in the java code... it was interpreting the project directory as the output directory. Thank you for all of the help though, you guys gave some very useful information!

Answer (score 2):

Thy this one?

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", @"/c C:\Directory\Process.cmd -x 1000 -y 1000 C:\Input\input.txt");
```

AFAIK, '@' prepends verbatim strings, wich do not requires backslash masking )

Answer (score 1):

The file may be getting created, but not where you think. Use

```
prs.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "yourpath"
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory.aspx

> The WorkingDirectory property must be set if UserName and Password are
>   provided. If the property is not set, the default working directory is
>   %SYSTEMROOT%\system32.
>
> If the directory is already part of the system path variable, you do
>   not have to repeat the directory's location in this property.
>
> The WorkingDirectory property behaves differently when UseShellExecute
>   is true than when UseShellExecute is false. When UseShellExecute is
>   true, the WorkingDirectory property specifies the location of the
>   executable. If WorkingDirectory is an empty string, the current
>   directory is understood to contain the executable.
>
> When UseShellExecute is false, the WorkingDirectory property is not
>   used to find the executable. Instead, it is used by the process that
>   is started and only has meaning within the context of the new process.

I deleted this after realizing that a path is passed in as an argument and was probably using hardcoded path logic for the file it writes to, but since a comment has referenced this, I'll undelete in case it is still of assistance.